# Is it possible to disable browser caching with code?

Tags: php, browser-cache

I know that there are other posts about disabling caching.  I've read all of them that I can find and am still having a problem, so please be kind and don't kick me for starting a new thread.

Here's the deal, I am working on a site that a landlord can use to list all of their properties.  It's sort of like an MLS based site that a realtor would use.

The problem that I'm having wouldn't be a problem for me, but it will be for my client who isn't very bright (I can say that, she's a family member).  Once a property is set up and all of the various pictures are uploaded there is an option to edit any of that data as well as delete any of the existing pictures.  If you delete a picture, all works well but the browser caching makes it appear as if nothing happened.  Hit F5 (in Firefox) to refresh the page and everything looks like it should.

The problem has to do with how I chose to name the photos that are uploaded.  The photos are renamed using the property address info with the number of the picture appended.  For example: 3505Cardinalpic1.jpg, 3505Cardinalpic2.jpg, 3505Cardinalpic3.jpg, etc.  If I were to delete the first one, for example, the following pictures are renamed to keep the naming order intact.  They would be come 3505Cardinalpic1.jpg, and 3505Cardinalpic2.jpg, for example.  Both surviving pictures are the 2nd and 3rd pictures from the pre-existing sequence of 3.

When the page reloads after one picture is deleted, it loads the pictures from cache because the filename didn't change, only the source file itself.

I figure that I could fix this by rewriting my php that handles the pictures so that the file name is appended with a timestamp or something that would make each name still recognizable but unique but I want to make sure there is no easier way to do that before I go in there and futz with something that's working.

I'm intentionally not posting code because I don't think it's a code issue and the problem description is already long enough.  If you'd like to see a section of my code, just ask.

I've tried this with no luck:
[test php disabled caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923655/test-php-disabled-caching)

I've tried appending my url with a timestamp to make it unique and that didn't help either.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Why are you rewriting the existing filenames? Forcing the browser to always reload each image (with no cache) just isn't a good practice. Best case is that you get the browser to not cache and then the perception of performance of the app will not be very good.

Comment: load the images using php's readfile(). There you can use php headers to prevent caching

Comment: i believe you can disable the caching on your clients computer for the particular site.

Comment: I'm not all that worried about the performance because it will only affect this one page on the admin side of the site.

To be honest, I wrote the php to handle the photos a while back and would do it differently now if I were to do it over again.  It sounds like I might be headed that way anyway.

I'm self taught and given what I have to deal with I think I did OK.

Comment: The suggestion below worked and I'm going to mark it as an accepted answer.  Thanks for your suggestions.  I promise to go back and recode the source of my problems instead of relying on this bandaid long-term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force the browser to not cache the file, link it with a changing parameter. If you do that  :

`<img src="3505Cardinalpic2.jpg?001"/>`

and just after, that

`<img src="3505Cardinalpic2.jpg?002"/>`

the browser will reload the image because he is not sure this is the same. If you want never caching, you can put a timestamp as parameter.

But it's not good to disable caching, so maybe you can change the value only when there is a modification in your album ?

Comment: That's interesting.  I'll give that a shot.  Thanks.  I know that I need to go back and fix the source of the problem and plan on doing that, I just don't have a lot of time to delve into that right now

Comment: That works.  Thanks for the quick and outside-of-the-box response.